# Remove a comment if user does not exist Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, null

I get an error `undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass` when I try to access a post with a comment from a user that has been deleted in the DB.

I wonder: how can I remove the comments that has been created by users who no longer exists "on the fly"?

I tried something like this

```
<%= div_for(comment) do %>
    <% if comment.user.email.nil?%>
        <% comment.destroy %>
    <%else%>
        <p><%= comment.body %></p>
        <p class="comment-submitted-by"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago by
        <%= comment.user.email %></p>
    <%end%>
```

but I still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still getting an error because you've referenced `comment.user.email`, and `user` is `nil`. You need to check `comment.user.nil?`, or you're also at risk for deleting a comment just because a user's email is missing (though maybe you disallow that):

```
<% if comment.user.nil? %>
  <% comment.destroy %>
```

---

Cleaning up on the fly is going to be finicky and cumbersome. What it looks like you want is [`dependent: :destroy`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#dependent) on your `User#comments` association.

```
class User
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Then when your `User` is removed, all of their `Comment`s will be too, and you don't have to worry about it at display time.

Since there are existing orphaned comments, you can clean them out with a simple SQL statement:

```
DELETE FROM comments WHERE user_id NOT IN (
  SELECT id FROM users
)
```

Or your Rails console:

```
Comments.find_each { |c| c.destroy if c.user.nil? }
```

Comment: Very good answer, this solved a lot of problems for me!

I have a follow up question. In my app I have a model for Users, links and comments. A user has_many :links, a link has_many :comments.

What if a user has commented on a link that is not his and he then deletes his account. Then in my case his links would disappear, but by the looks if it his comments will remain. What should I add in the links model so that the comments on that link by that user also gets destroyed?

Sorry if I dont make any sense.

Comment: If users can comment on other users' links, I assume `Comment` has `link_id, user_id`, so `User#has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy` should clear their comments without affecting the other users' links. To also remove the destroyed user's links, `User#has_many :links, dependent: :destroy`, and to clean up comments when the link is destroyed, `Link#has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy`. Basically, add the `:dependent` to any association that needs cleaning.

Comment: @Kristján `Comments.find_each { |c| c.destroy if c.user.nil? }` gets N+1 queries issue, it should be `Comment.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON comments.user_id = users.id').where(users: {id: nil}).destroy_all`

Comment: Thanks for the optimization @HieuPham :)

Comment: Comments belongs_to :user in Comments.rb, but there is no has_many :comments in the User.rb. Can I just add has_many :comments in user to make dependent: :destroy work?

Comment: @Flux Yep, that's where it should go. You need to put it on the object being destroyed - otherwise Rails can't notice there's something to clean up.

Comment: I'd use a foreign key rather than `dependent: :destroy` `add_foreign_key :comments, users, on_delete: :cascade`

Answer (score 0):

Removing some comments from a thread might make it hard to understand the remaining comments, because of missing context.

Therefore I would like to suggest another approach: Just display *deleted user* instead of the user's email when the user was deleted.

A simple implementation might look like this:

```
<%= div_for(comment) do %>
  <p><%= comment.body %></p>
  <p class="comment-submitted-by">
    <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago by
    <%= comment.user ? comment.user.email : 'deleted user' %>
  </p>
<%end%>
```